# javafx: adding tabs dynamically when user opens a new file

Tags: dynamic, menu, tabs, javafx

This is my edited question.. I want a new tab to be displayed in the same window. In the main window, i have a menu bar. Suppose the user clicks open, a new tab must be created in the same window below the menu bar and so on..

Kindly give me some pointers since I am a beginner in javafx. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: `Stage mystage = new Stage();` creates a new window, and `mystage.show()` displays it. You need a reference to the existing `TabPane`; just call `getTabs().add(...)` on that.

Comment: Thanks James_D for the response. I tried adding  tabs.getTabs().add(tab) line to the existing code after mystage.show(). I am getting 2 tabs next to each other, but I want a new tab to be created dynamically in the same window next to each other. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Why are you calling `Stage mystage = new Stage();` and  `mystage.show()` at all? You said you didn't want a new window. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: James_d Kindly refer my edited question. Thanks

Comment: I found a solution to my question: final Tab tab=new Tab("Tab " + (tab_help.getTabs().size() + 1));
     tab_help.getTabs().add(new Tab());
    Added this code. tab_help is fx:id of tab pane

Answer (score 0):

use tabpane and add tabs to it programmatically

```
 TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
 Tab mytab = new Tab("tab to be created programmatically");
 mytab.setContent(put your data here);
 tabPane.getTabs().add(mytab);
```

the tabpane should be in the window/node/scene that you are flirting with ...that's all