# Javafx : Adding contents to the tabs based on chosen file

Tags: dynamic, tabs, javafx

I am trying to add dynamic contents to tabs. The scenario is when the user clicks on the open file menu, a tab should open displaying the contents of the chosen file. The scene is a border pane which has a pane and tab pane. The contents of respective files are displayed on the pane and should vary according the selected tab.

I appreciate any help to implement this scenario.

Comment: You appear to be repeatedly asking duplicates of [javafx: adding tabs dynamically when user opens a new file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591505/javafx-adding-tabs-dynamically-when-user-opens-a-new-file). You indicated in the comments there that you had found a solution to that. If you now have a different question, that is not clear from this. I recommend you post some code, explain what you want it to do and how what it is doing differs from that. Reading the guidance on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) may also help.

Comment: I managed to create tabs for every file opened but I need to add contents of the file to the tabs. My previous question was to create tabs dynamically which I created but now the problem is to add the respective contents to each tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
Tab tabB = new Tab();
tabB.setText("Tab B");
tabB.setContent(yourcontent);
tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);
mainPane.setCenter(tabPane);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainpane, 400, 300, Color.WHITE););
```